# Files and Folders services do not appear

Tags: finder, services

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

I enabled "Files and Folders" in Services under Shortcuts in the Keyboard tab and I enabled all services under Files and Folders.

The services do not appear in the Finder's Services menu. I tried relaunching Finder, entering /System/Library/CoreServices/pbs into a terminal, and restarting my computer. It still does not work. What might be going on?

Comment: They only appear depending on the kind of the "selected file type", or "folder" or something related to the selected file: Eg: Some services only appear for .JPG or images, other only appear for Folders, other only for TXT, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was silly.
As @Prado points out in the comment above, I had to select a file or folder first to access these services.

Comment: Agree, this is so silly, finder current opened folder should by default be selected,  not this supid manual select way.